# What is this beetle-like, brown-spotted flying insect?

Tags: identification, peppers, insects

I found another strange insect flying around in my garden today that I'm hoping to get identification on.

[This website](http://www.landcareresearch.co.nz/research/biosystematics/invertebrates/invertid/list_category.asp?Ca_ID=10) was helpful previously, but I haven't been able to figure it out this time. It flys around pretty bee-like, but also sort of burrowed when it fell into the soil.

[image: Insect to identify crawling on my pepper plant (image 1)]

[image: Insect to identify crawling on my pepper plant (image 2)]

Answer (score 2):

Good photo, and I'm pretty sure it is [Bumble flower beetle](https://www.google.ru/search?q=Bumble%20flower%20beetle).

These beetles don't do anything bad to healthy plants, so you don't need to worry about them.